# Python - PyQT5 print output inside the QTextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a pyqt5 code to print the dictionary output inside the QTextEdit

```
#code:-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(565, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.text_output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 501, 251))
        self.text_output.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.text_output.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.text_output.setObjectName("text_output")
        self.btn_dict = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_dict.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 280, 101, 21))
        self.btn_dict.setObjectName("btn_dict")
        self.btn_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 280, 101, 21))
        self.btn_clear.setObjectName("btn_clear")
        self.btn_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 280, 101, 21))
        self.btn_exit.setObjectName("btn_exit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 565, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_dict.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PrintDictionary"))
        self.btn_clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.btn_exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    def dictionary(self):
        new_dict = {
              'Name' : 'Ron',
              'Age' : '21',
              'city' : 'NY'
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So instead of printing output on console , i want to the output inside QTextEdit when clicked on PrintDictionary button as well as how to clear QTextEdit when clicked on clear button or exit application when clicked on exit button

I'm new to PYQT5 so please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `dictionary` function does not necessarily have to be a member of the class, and since you do not pass the self to it, I assume that you have badly indentured your code in that part.

Going to the point, you must use the clicked signal and call a lambda function that performs the action through the append and clear method of QTextEdit.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        [...]

    def dictionary(self):
        new_dict = {
            'Name' : 'Ron',
            'Age' : '21',
            'city' : 'NY'
        }
        return new_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.btn_dict.clicked.connect(lambda: ui.text_output.append(str(ui.dictionary())))
    ui.btn_clear.clicked.connect(ui.text_output.clear)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ eyllanesc thanks for reply. But QTextEdit shows none and output is displayed on console

Comment: @Rohan I have updated my code, but you have to see that dictionary must return new_dict.